# Retrofit Periodic call with Pagination

Tags: android, api, retrofit

I am currently using the Retrofit2.0 to poll the server .I am getting the result in x second but the problem is page number is not updating in the API.Lets come to the code for better clarification

```
private void startPolling() throws Exception {
        Log.e("APP CONSTANT","" + current_page);
        MrSaferWebService service =  ServiceFactory.createRetrofitService(MrSaferWebService.class,  AppConstants.BASE_URL);
        final Observable<ReportResponse> reportResponseObservable =  service.getListOfInciden("get_report", current_page, 5, incident_lat,  incident_long);
        Observable.interval(0,20,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<ReportResponse>> () {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<ReportResponse> call(Long  aLong) {
                        return reportResponseObservable;
                    }
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Action1<ReportResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(ReportResponse response) {
                        Log.i("HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL", "Response from HEARTBEAT");
                        ActivityUtils.showProgress(false, mRootView, mProgressView, mContext);
                        if (response.getStatus() == 1) {
                            current_page = current_page + 1;
                             if (!response.getReportList().isEmpty()) {
                                addItems(response.getReportList());
                           }
                             else{
                                //do nothing
                            }

                        } else {
                            Log.e("MY ERROR", "" + "SOME ERROR OCCURED");
                        }
                    }
                }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                        ActivityUtils.showProgress(true, mRootView, mProgressView, mContext);
                        // TODO: 22/03/16 ADD ERROR HANDLING
                    }
                });

     }
```

As you can see i have incremented the  current_page by 1 every time on 
SuccessFull Response but when i check the Log the current_page value are increased only once and after that log are not there and hence there value is also not increasing..So it taking the the same page number every time and giving me the Duplicate response.

Please help me to find what i am missing.

Comment: Where's ``current_page`` defined? Is it an object attribute? Does it work if you add ``volatile``? -  ``volatile int current_page;`` and are you sure the on error action is not getting called?

Comment: It defined in the class level like this int current_page =1

Answer (score 1):

After spending more than a day i just changed Action with Subscriber and everything seems to be working .I don't know what happen internally but it works . I am still trying to figure it out what the difference between Action and Subscriber.
Below are my updated code which did the tricks.

```
private void startPolling() throws Exception {
        final MrSaferWebService service =  ServiceFactory.createRetrofitService(MrSaferWebService.class,  AppConstants.BASE_URL);
        Observable
                .interval(0,20,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<ReportResponse>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<ReportResponse> call(Long aLong) {
                        Log.e("PAGE", "" + current_page);
                        return service.getListOfInciden("get_report", current_page, 5, incident_lat, incident_long);
                    }
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<ReportResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        if (mProgressView !=null &&  mRootView !=null) {
                            ActivityUtils.showProgress(false, mRootView, mProgressView, mContext);
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(ReportResponse response) {
                        if (mProgressView !=null &&  mRootView !=null) {
                            ActivityUtils.showProgress(false, mRootView, mProgressView, mContext);
                        }
                        if (response.getStatus() == 1) {
                            if (!response.getReportList().isEmpty()){
                                current_page = current_page + 1;
                                addItems(response.getReportList());
                            }
                            else{
                                //do nothing
                            }

                        } else {
                            Log.e("MY ERROR", "" + "SOME ERROR OCCURED");
                        }
                    }
                });

     }
```

Comment: Hi. I am trying to implement a similar pagination implementation. And I'm stuck. You are using the Observable with Interval of 20Seconds if I'm correct? What if I want it to request only when it's done? Thanks This is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38837499/retrofit2-tail-recursion-using-rxjava-rxandroid?noredirect=1#comment65044509_38837499

Comment: Nope. Sorry. Have you seen my codebase. Should I use `repeatWhen` there or use it the way you did?