# Retrofit2 Tail Recursion Using RxJava / RxAndroid

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I am really trying to get a hang of using `Retrofit` with `RxJava / RxAndroid`. I've done this using normal `Retrofit2 Callback` method in a previous app without the use of `Reactive Programming` and it worked fine. So, here is it. I need to `Tail Recall` a function meant to fetch all `Local Government` from the server. The `API` uses pagination `(I have to construct the URL with ?page=1, perPage=2)`. I've to do this till I've the whole data. So, below is my `Rx` code

```
    public static Observable<LgaListResponse> getPages(Context acontext) {
    String token = PrefUtils.getToken(acontext);
    BehaviorSubject<Integer> pageControl = BehaviorSubject.<Integer>create(1);
    Observable<LgaListResponse> ret2 = pageControl.asObservable().concatMap(integer -> {
        if (integer > 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Integer: " + integer);
            return ServiceGenerator.createService(ApiService.class, token)
                    .getLgas(String.valueOf(integer), String.valueOf(21))
                    .doOnNext(lgaListResponse -> {
                        if (lgaListResponse.getMeta().getPage() != lgaListResponse.getMeta().getPageCount()) {
                            pageControl.onNext(initialPage + 1);
                        } else {
                            pageControl.onNext(-1);
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            return Observable.<LgaListResponse>empty().doOnCompleted(pageControl::onCompleted);
        }
    });

    return Observable.defer(() -> ret2);
}
```

And my ServiceGenerator Class

```
    public class ServiceGenerator {

        private static final String TAG = "ServiceGen";
        private static OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

        private static Retrofit.Builder retrofitBuilder =
                new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(BuildConfig.HOST)
                        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(CustomGsonParser.returnCustomParser()));

        public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, String token) {

            builder.addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY));
            /*builder.addNetworkInterceptor(new StethoInterceptor());*/
            builder.connectTimeout(30000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            builder.readTimeout(30000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            if (token != null) {
                Interceptor interceptor = chain -> {
                    Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                            .addHeader("x-mobile", "true")
                            .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token).build();
                    return chain.proceed(newRequest);
                };
                builder.addInterceptor(interceptor);
            }
            OkHttpClient client = builder.build();

            Retrofit retrofit = retrofitBuilder.client(client).build();
            Log.e(TAG, retrofit.baseUrl().toString());
            return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
        }

        public static Retrofit retrofit() {
            OkHttpClient client = builder.build();
            return retrofitBuilder.client(client).build();
        }

        public static class CustomGsonParser {

            public static Gson returnCustomParser(){
                return new GsonBuilder()
                        .setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                                return f.getDeclaringClass().equals(RealmObject.class);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
                                return false;
                            }
                        })
                        .create();
            }
        }
    }
```

So, I noticed on the first call, I get a response, but on the second one, the `440Error` is thrown. The URL is formed, but the request throws a `400Error`. I don't know why it's throwing a `400` everything is working fine if I use `POSTMAN` to test. And, I tested with my old code too. The `Log` is too long, so I put it in `pastebin` [LOGS](http://pastebin.com/cu4681Nk) any help thanks. I've written most of this app with `RxAndroid / RxJava`. Thanks

Comment: Well firstly recursion is not the best way to paginate using RxJava and Retrofit. See one of the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37326380/paginate-observable-results-without-recursion-rxjava) for a better way. Second, where are you subscribing to the observable? You seem to have multiple subscriptions which all trigger new requests since the Observable you're generating is "cold".

Comment: I believe this line `.subscribe(new Subscriber<LgaListResponse>() {` is meant to subscribe me to `onComplete`, `onError` and `onNext` right? And these `(clientBus.hasObservers())` `clientBus` is a singleton. So, it's not generated multiple times. And it's just to send message to the UI

Comment: Yes but at some point you call create an LgaHandler using `getInstance' and then call `getLgas` don't you? Now do you call this multiple times?

Comment: Nope. getInstance() is called just once. That's a singleton. So, the inner function getLgas() does the remaining call. This is the one I did in the old app without the use of `RxJava` https://gist.github.com/tonespy/c46d6d6729ab6618f906b050a2f22b1a @JohnWowUs

Comment: The logs you link show two `GET http://theUrl.com/lga?page=1&per_page=21 http/1.1` lines and three `GET http://theUrl.com/lga?page=2&per_page=21 http/1.1` lines.

Comment: @JohnWowUs I've debugged everything. It's only called once it's called. I noticed it too. And, I do this immediately user `login` into `application`. I debugged to my service generator. It's only called once, I don't know why the Observable is calling it twice though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you simplify things (and remove recursion). First build up your pages using something like

```
public static Observable<LgaListResponse> getPages(Context acontext, int initialPage, int perPage) {  
    String token = PrefUtils.getToken(acontext);
    BehaviorSubject<Integer> pagecontrol = BehaviorSubject.<Integer>create(initialPage);
    Observable<LgaListResponse> ret2 = pagecontrol.asObservable().concatMap(
        new Func1<Integer,Observable<LgaListResponse>>() {
            Observable<LgaListResponse> call(Integer pageNumber) {
                if (pageNumber > 0) {
                    return ServiceGenerator.createService(ApiService.class, token)
                                           .getLgas(String.valueOf(aKey), String.valueOf(perPage))
                                           .doOnNext(
                                                new Action1<LgaListResponse>() {
                                                    void call(LgaListResponse page) {
                                                        if (page.getMeta().getPage() != page.getMeta().getPageCount()) {
                                                            pagecontrol.onNext(page.getMeta().getNextPage());
                                                        } else {
                                                            pagecontrol.onNext(-1);
                                                        }         
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            );
                }                                               
                else {
                    return Observable.<LgaListResponse>empty().doOnCompleted(()->pagecontrol.onCompleted());
                }           
            }
        }
    );

    return Observable.defer(
                new Func0<Observable<LgaListResponse>() {
                    Observable<LgaListResponse> call() {
                        return ret2;
                    }
                }
            );            
}
```

then subscribe to the resulting observable. It looks horrible because I've avoided using lambdas but it should work.

Comment: I'm really grateful for the help. But, I'm still experiencing the same error. I think my Service Generator is the cause. I've edited my question

Comment: I think perhaps you should create the service once and reuse it instead of creating a service for every new page.