# Optimizing Retrofit Request To Prevent Lagging

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I do a huge polling when user login into my app. At the moment, we don't have much **payload**. But, the **payloads** are growing by the 100s daily at the moment. Which makes us have around 300 records per-user. And this, is the first week. So, we started **optimizing** for the next **thousands**. **API** has been well modified, but the Android app is shaky.

I have a request where a user have max of Two **Territories** for now, and I need to fetch all the **Items** in each **Territory**. So, I did this:

```
/**
* This is to get all user territories and for each and every territory, fetch all items there;
*/
private Observable<ItemListResponse> getAlltemIByTerritory() {

    List<String> territories = PrefUtils.getUserTerritories(context);
    return Observable.from(territories).flatMap(territory -> fetchAllTerritoryItemPaged(territory, 1));
}

/**
* This is to fetch all items in a passed territory. There's a per_page of 21.
*/
private Observable<ItemListResponse> fetchAllTerritoryItemPaged(String territory, int page) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Each territory page: " + page);

    return itemAPI.getIems("Bearer " + PrefUtils.getToken(context), page, 21, territory)
            .flatMap(itemListResponse -> {
                Meta meta = itemListResponse.getBakeResponse().getMeta();
                Observable<ItemListResponse> thisPage = Observable.just(itemListResponse);
                if (meta.getPage() != meta.getPageCount() && meta.getPageCount() > 0) {
                    Observable<ItemListResponse> nextPage = fetchAllTerritoryItemPaged(territory, page + 1);

                    return thisPage.concatWith(nextPage);
                } else {
                    return thisPage;
                }
            });
}
```

**Utilizing the Observable**

```
public void getAlltemIByTerritory(APIRequestListener apiRequestListener) {
    realm.executeTransaction(realm1 -> realm1.where(RealmItem.class).findAll().deleteAllFromRealm());

    getAlltemIByTerritory()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<ItemListResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Completed Item");
                    apiRequestListener.didComplete(WhichSync.ITEM);
                    unsubscribe();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    handleError(e, apiRequestListener, WhichSync.ITEM);
                    unsubscribe();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(ItemListResponse itemListResponse) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "In the handler next " + itemListResponse.toString());
                    realm.executeTransaction(realm1 -> {
                        for (Item itemData : itemListResponse.getItemResponse().getData()) {
                            RealmItem realmItem = realm1.where(RealmItem.class).equalTo("id", itemData.getId()).findFirst();
                            if (realmItem != null)
                                realmItem.deleteFromRealm();

                            realm1.copyToRealm(Item.copyBakeryToRealm(itemData));
                        }
                    });

                    apiRequestListener.onProgress(itemListResponse.getItemResponse().getMeta(), itemListResponse.getItemResponse().getData().size(), WhichSync.ITEM);
                }
            });
}
```

`Log.e(TAG, "Each territory page: " + page);` This line and this line `Log.e(TAG, "In the handler next " + itemListResponse.toString());` reads to 23 for a 1780 record. With 21 records per_page. And then, the second line stop showing. Then, the view has hang. And then, when the first one is done, I then see the second spitting out logs afterwards.

This works fine, just that when the record is over 700 (The first try was with a 1780 record), there's a huge lag on the UI. And on mostly `pre-lollipops` it crashes with `NoClassDefined Exception` and sometimes it works. But, the lag is still always there.

Any help with optimizing the code, thanks.

Comment: The problem seems to be recursion depth in `fetchAllTerritoryItemPaged`. With 21 items per page you'll rapidly reach the limit. See the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37326380/paginate-observable-results-without-recursion-rxjava) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38837499/retrofit2-tail-recursion-using-rxjava-rxandroid).

Comment: Yeah. I fixed it two nights ago. I wanted to add the answer here. Just been busy. Had to strip out the tail recursion and utilize `BehaviorSubject` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Tail Recursion` here:

```
/**
* This is to fetch all items in a passed territory. There's a per_page of 21.
*/
private Observable<ItemListResponse> fetchAllTerritoryItemPaged(String territory, int page) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Each territory page: " + page);

    return itemAPI.getIems("Bearer " + PrefUtils.getToken(context), page, 21, territory)
            .flatMap(itemListResponse -> {
                Meta meta = itemListResponse.getItemResponse().getMeta();
                Observable<ItemListResponse> thisPage = Observable.just(itemListResponse);
                if (meta.getPage() != meta.getPageCount() && meta.getPageCount() > 0) {
                    Observable<ItemListResponse> nextPage = fetchAllTerritoryItemPaged(territory, page + 1);

                    return thisPage.concatWith(nextPage);
                } else {
                    return thisPage;
                }
            });
}
```

is the one causing the problem. Luckily, Rx provides us with `BehaviorSubject`.

So, I did something like this instead

```
private Observable<ItemListResponse> fetchAllTerritoryItemPaged(String territory, int page) {

    BehaviorSubject<Integer> pageControl = BehaviorSubject.create(page);
    Observable<ItemListResponse> ret = pageControl.asObservable().concatMap(integer -> {

        if (integer > 0) {

            return itemAPI.getIems("Bearer " + PrefUtils.getToken(context), integer, 21, territory)
                    .doOnNext(itemListResponse -> {
                        Meta meta = itemListResponse.getItemResponse().getMeta();
                        if (meta.getPage() != meta.getPageCount() && meta.getPageCount() > 0) {
                            pageControl.onNext(integer + 1);
                        } else {
                            pageControl.onNext(-1);
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            return Observable.<ItemListResponse>empty().doOnCompleted(pageControl::onCompleted);
        }
    });

    return Observable.defer(() -> ret);
}
```

Which not only remove the lag, but also request comes in pretty fast