# Fetching A Paginating URL with Retrofit2 and RxJava

Tags: rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I am trying to make API request that requires me to fetch all data in that `model` from the server. Fetching is not the problem, it's the fact that the payload is paged with something like this 

`"meta": {
    "page": 1,
    "perPage": 20,
    "previousPage": false,
    "nextPage": 2,
    "pageCount": 2,
    "total": 37
  }`
 
And from what I've read, tail recursion while using `RxJava` makes your `Observables` become cold. An example is this question here [StackOverFlow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38837499/retrofit2-tail-recursion-using-rxjava-rxandroid?noredirect=1#comment65044509_38837499) he's is spuning multiple Observers based on the comments. I don't know much about `RxJava` either. Then I came across this question [RxJava With Interval and Flatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37993484/retrofit-periodic-call-with-pagination). He made use of Interval. But then, interval would tell the request to be made every `20Seconds` I can't set a timer on a request because it can be slower or faster. It's better to leave it to the request itself. So, my problem is how can I implement a `Request` that requires pagination just like the first `Stack Question`. Any help would be appreciated. My code base is somewhat like the first question URL.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, but I guess that you wish to obtain all models from observable.

Below code is pseudo code to explain how to do that.

Your `Response` class and `Model` class may be like this:

```
public class Response {
    Meta meta;
    List<Model> models;
}

public class Model {
    ...
}

public class Meta {
    int page;
    int perPage;
    boolean previousPage;
    int nextPage;
    int pageCount;
    int total;
}
```

Create `Observable.OnSubscribe` which requests and emits all model.
like this:

```
public Observable<List<Model>> getAllModels(ApiService apiService) {
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Model>() {

        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super Model> subscriber) {
            try {

                final int perPage = 20;

                for (int page = 1, pageCount = 1; page <= pageCount; page++) {
                    Call<Response> call = apiService.getModels(page, perPage);
                    Response response = call.execute().body();
                    subscriber.onNext(response.models);

                    pageCount = response.meta.pageCount;
                }

                subscriber.onCompleted();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                subscriber.onError(e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Call above method. like this:

```
ApiService apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);

getAllModels(apiService)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(...);
```

I know this code is not tail recursion call. But I hope this helps.

Comment: It helps. But, I implemented it using `BehaviorSubject` instead. The code is shorter. Thanks anyway